# Multisite path issue

Tags: 7, multi-sites, uri

Our multisite is having issues.

we have a subsite called /wikifix
some of the URLs in this subsite are /wikifix/wiki/...

now we have another subsite called /wiki.
as soon as we make our symlink, the pages on /wikifix that have wikifix/wiki/ in their path start giving drupal page not found errors.
Testing on another subsite in the multisite /kids shows similar issues, /kids/wiki also gives page not found errors

both sites work and are accessible, the issue is only when the path contains the name of a different subsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two issues causing this were both in the .htaccess:

this line was commented out:

```
RewriteBase /
```

and then we had to add this per subsite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wikifix
RewriteRule ^ wikifix/index.php [L]
```

including the first 3 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wiki
RewriteRule ^ wiki/index.php [L]
```

since both subsites start with /wiki, it was also important to have the RewriteCond for wikifix BEFORE the RewriteCond for wiki